# variable for check in jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var data = [
    { Name: "Joe", Team: 1, Title: A },
    { Name: "Jack", Team: 2, Title: B },
    { Name: "William", Team: 2, Title: B },
    { Name: "Averell", Team: 1, Title: A }
]
```

```
<ul>
    {{each data}}
        <li><ul> ${Title}</ul></li>
        <li> Name : ${Name} TeamId :${Team} </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I need group person by Title. 
my output should be like this.

```
A
-------------
Name : Joe TeamId : 1
Name : Averell TeamId : 1

B
------
Name : Jack TeamId : 2
Name : William TeamId : 2
```

I m tryig to print title if is not exit. but it prints title for each person.
Can i use variable in template to check title or Is there any posible way in jQuery template ?

Comment: I assume you can't change the initial data structure, right ?

Comment: yes i cant change the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LINQ to JS, a library that you can find at http://jslinq.codeplex.com/ . It allows you to make queries in JS structures and I think it will work perfectly for you.
See the documentation to learn some examples, but I think something like it will work:

```
//Create a array of the possible titles you have 
var titles = ['A','B'];
var arrayAnswers;

//iterate inside this array to get each group you need
for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
       arrayAnswers = JSLINQ(data).Where(function(item){ return item.Title == titles[i]; }); 
       //print the result
}
```